# Filtering items by category with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, filtering

I am very new to Laravel, most of the problems I have I solve with reading documentation or by using google. This one I can't.

I want to create 'all products' page like this https://www.socialprintstudio.com/products/

I have two laravel models, [item] and [itemcategory] and they are related like this.

itemcategory model

```
public function items(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\item');
}
```

item model

```
public function itemcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\itemcategory');
}
```

In my controller I add items and categories to my view

```
->with('categories', $categories)
->with('items', $items);
```

Now I can use all of the data in my view, **now what I want to do is, that when  user clicks on certain category, it only shows products that belong to that category**

Should I save some category IDs in "data-id" variable and manage those with stuff like jquery?

I don't know any other way

Comment: In my opinion you should build a resource containing logic of getting items category-wise and return it in your response then display it in your view